# T-SQL What does the error message Msg 10709,

Tags: sql, t-sql

This is my code and I added up the same rows so it matched how come it still saying the error?

```
Use KudlerFineFoods
INSERT INTO Employee (Lastname,Firstname,[Address],City,[State],TelephoneAreaCode,TelephoneNumber,EmployerInformationReport,HiredDate,Salary,Gender,Age,JobTitleID)

VALUES 
('Edelman','Glenn','175 Bishop Lane','La    Jolla','CA','619','5550199','https://ecampus.phoenix.edu/secure/aapd/CIST/VOP/Business/Kudl er2/intranet/docs/Glenn%20Edelman%202004.pdf','07/10/2003','$21,500','m','1979/12/01',4),
 ('McMullen','Eric', '763 Church Street','Lemon Grove','CA','619','5550135', 'https://ecampus.phoenix.edu/secure/aapd/CIST/VOP/Business/Kudler2/intranet/docs/Eric%20McMullen%202004.pdf',
  '2002/11/01','13,500.00','m','1992/01/01',3),
('Slentz','Raj', '123 Torrey Drive','North Clairmont','CA','619','5550123','https://ecampus.phoenix.edu/secure/aapd/CIST/VOP/Business/Kudler2/intranet/docs/Raj%20Slentz%202004.pdf','2001/06/01','48,000.00','m','1978/02/04',2),
 ('Broun','Erin', '2045 Parkway Apt 2BY','Encinitas' ,'CA','760','555','5550100', 'https://ecampus.phoenix.edu/secure/aapd/CIST/VOP/Business/Kudler2/intranet/docs/Erin%20Broun%202004.pdf','2003/12/03','$10,530.00','f','19880201',3),
 ('Carpenter','Donald', '927 Seond Street', 'Encinitas','CA', '927','5550154','https://ecampus.phoenix.edu/secure/aapd/CIST/VOP/Business/Kudler2/intranet/docs/Donald%20Carpenter%202004.pdf','2003/11/01','$15,000.00','m','1995/01/01',9),
 ('Esquivez','David','1083 N. Coast HWY Apt 902','Encinitas','CA','760','5550108','https://ecampus.phoenix.edu/secure/aapd/CIST/VOP/Business/Kudler2/intranet/docs/David%20Esquivez%202004.pdf','2003/07/25','$18,500.00','m','1991/01/01',8),
 ('Sharp','Nancy', '10793 Montecino Road','Domona','CA','858','5550135', 'https://ecampus.phoenix.edu/secure/aapd/CIST/VOP/Business/Kudler2/intranet/docs/Nancy%20Sharp%202004.pdf','2003/07/12','$21,000.00','f','1992/07/07',4);
```

Comment: The row beginning `('Broun'` has a different number of columns than the others. SSMS helpfully highlights this with a red squiggle and mouseover tells you the problem.

Comment: I wish I would of saw that an hour ago :) thanks

Comment: There is a value for '555' in that row what @MartinSmith referenced. I think you just misstyped it: ,'760','555','5550100',  -> maybe ,'760','5550100', ?

Comment: Next time try them row by row ;)

Comment: THank you all for all the great comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HiredDate in the 1st Column has a different Syntax:

```
'07/10/2003'
```

And the Broun row has `'555','5550100'` while the `'555'` is an extra data comparing with other rows

Comment: I am sorry I should of seen this but I have been working on this school project since 9am and it is 4:22 pm right now I am exhausted you guys are great :)

Comment: Go get some sleep ... nice dreams

Comment: I will still not done I have to display the two tables and the book I have kind of sucks so it complicates it all. :)